# Run a for loop over a list, save each list object in output matrix

Tags: r

I want to run a for loop over a list. I have 3 questions:

1. I wonder how I select  each list in "i in 1:list", when doing the same for a data frame it can be for(i in 1:ncol(df)), but how should this be written for a list?
2. I also wonder how I could "add on" the values for each loop to the " output" matrix?
3. How to convert a list to a data frame. When doing it like data.frame(df3) they will be added column wise, number of rows will always be 3.

Many thanks if someone has suggestions!

```
    name <- rep("gg",3) 
id <- LETTERS[1:3]
emmeans <- runif(1:3)
SE <- runif(1:3)
p <- rep(c(0.001),3)
df <- data.frame(name,id, emmeans,p)
df
df  <- list(df)

name <- rep("ff",3) 
id <- LETTERS[1:3]
emmeans <- runif(1:3)
SE <- runif(1:3)
p <- rep(c(0.003),3)

df2 <- data.frame(name,id, emmeans,p)
df2 <- list(df2)

df3 <- list(df,df2)
df3
> df3
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  name id   emmeans     p
1   gg  A 0.2248491 0.001
2   gg  B 0.4213938 0.001
3   gg  C 0.3671521 0.001


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  name id   emmeans     p
1   ff  A 0.2561801 0.003
2   ff  B 0.1705811 0.003
3   ff  C 0.9714178 0.003

output <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=5)

for(i in 1:list){ # what could be written here?
  d <- as.data.frame(df3[[i]])
  for(j in 1:nrow(d)){
    output[i,1] <- d[1,3]
    output[i,2] <- d[2,3]
    output[i,3] <- d[3,3]
    output[i,4] <- d[1,4]
    output[i,5] <- d[1,1]
  }
}

#Wanted outcome:
output
     [,1]                [,2]                [,3]                [,4]    [,5]
[1,] "0.224849119782448" "0.421393777942285" "0.367152112303302" "0.001" "gg"
[2,] "0.256180095253512" "0.170581063022837" "0.971417842432857" "0.003" "ff"
```

Comment: 1. `length(df3)`, 2. `cbind`, 3. `dplyr::bind_rows(df3)`

Comment: But (2) is terribly inefficient - set up so that your output matrix is the right size from the start, and then replace the default values with your actual results in your loop, rather than "growing" your matrix by making it bigger every iteration.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas thanks fro your response! Do you have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your actual goal is. You have `output <- matrix(nrow=6, ncol=2)`, so you are already initializing `output` to some size - just make sure that size is the final size you want it to be.

Comment: It's also hard to tell what's going on with your set-up. E.g., you have `df <- data.frame(name,id, q1,q2)`, so `df` is a data frame. Then you do `df <- list(df)`, so now `df` is a list that contains only a data frame. And then ditto for `df2`. Then when you do `df3 <- list(df, df2)` you have a list that has 2 items, and each item is a list that contains a single data frame - a relatively complex data structure.

Comment: Why did `df` and `df2` become list themeslves *and* be put into `df3` - there doesn't seem to be any purpose to `df <- list(df)` and `df2 <- list(df2)` - is this inefficient code we should change, or is it a simplification of your actual data that requires this extra step for some reason?

Comment: And back to your actual goal - your code doesn't run as-is, and you don't show or describe your desired output, so I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, so I really can't help get you there. Your specific questions have been addressed...

Comment: @Gregor Thomas yes the code is wierd Im just trying to recreate the problem I have in my actual data. Therefore i made a data frame to a list.  In my real data I have a list with several items (or what to call it, as exemplified in df3), and I want to iterate over these and extract some data from each item and put it in another matrix, "output". Thats my goal! How would you do this?

Comment: How I would do it would depend on what I'm trying to extract and what format I want the result in. If you (**a** - best!) put your expected result in the question, or (**b** - second best) describe your exact goal in words, or (**c** - okay) comment the not-working code to make it's goals clear, then maybe I'd understand your goal and could help with it. (**a**) and (**b**) together would be preferable.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas Now I have updated the code! I realize there were some error. So I want to extract information from the items in the list (df3) into a new matrix (output) in another order. Now the code is not working. So, I wonder how to run a loop of the list to extract the information I want from each item and then how to store it in "output". Many thanks!

Comment: Okay, so based on the input you show and the output, it looks like you want your output to be a matrix with 1 row per element in `df3`. For each list item in `df3`, which is a sub-list, we will look at the *first* item of the sub-list (? is this right? What do we do if `df3[[1]]` includes multiple items? Multiple data frames?). For this data frame, we will extract the `emmeans` column as a vector, append the *first value from the `p` column* (is "first" right? In your example, all the p column values are equal. Is this always the case? Should we check? Take the first? The mean?...)

Comment: Then we also append the *first value in the `name` column* (same questions about `name` as `p` column - is *first* value right?). As the `name` column is non-numeric, this vector will be `character` class, and will form a row in the output.

Comment: This also assumes that all the data frames have the same number of rows - is this a safe assumption? Do we need to check the number of rows, fill missing rows with `NA`, truncate extra values?

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas The column "p" and "name" will have the same value in the three rows, it will always be like this. It is the effect of gg on id A,B,C. p= overall pvalue of the id A,B,C (yes, should have named id differently, like treatment or something). I just made it like this to make the same number of all columns and rows, so yes it will always be the same numbers of rows and columns

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas What do we do if df3[[1]] includes multiple items? Answer: The data structure will always be the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is weirdly structured enough, and the extraction is unique enough, that I think a `for` loop is the easiest way. Something like this:

```
output <- matrix(nrow = length(df3), ncol=5)
for(i in seq_along(df3)) {
  output[i, ] = with(df3[[i]], c(emmeans, p[1], name[1]))
}
output
#      [,1]                 [,2]               [,3]                [,4]    [,5]
# [1,] "0.0101301828399301" "0.21454192395322" "0.913734979229048" "0.003" "ff"
# [2,] "0.0101301828399301" "0.21454192395322" "0.913734979229048" "0.003" "ff"
```